# Is there a version of blender using Python 3.8?

Tags: python

I've doublechecked all versions of Blender releases here https://github.com/blender/blender/releases. There seems to be **NO** such a version that supports **Python 3.8** from within **CMakeLists.txt**.

Clearly, I cannot build any version of blender that need support of **Python3.9**, I decided to build **blender-2.92.0** that requires **Python3.7**.

However, it seems I have to turn **OFF** both **OpenImageIO** and **OpenColorIO**, otherwise I'll have the following **ERROR** message:

1. For **OpenColorIO**

```
[ 96%] Building C object source/blender/python/intern/CMakeFiles/bf_python.dir/bpy_driver.c.o
cd ....../blender-2.92.0/build/source/blender/python/intern && /usr/local/bin/cc -DBUILD_DATE -DNDEBUG -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -DWITH_AUDASPACE -DWITH_AVI -DWITH_BULLET -DWITH_CINEON -DWITH_COLLADA -DWITH_COMPOSITOR -DWITH_CYCLES -DWITH_CYCLES_EMBREE -DWITH_CYCLES_OSL -DWITH_DDS -DWITH_FFMPEG -DWITH_FLUID -DWITH_FREESTYLE -DWITH_HDR -DWITH_INPUT_NDOF -DWITH_INTERNATIONAL -DWITH_JACK -DWITH_LIBMV -DWITH_MOD_REMESH -DWITH_OCEANSIM -DWITH_OCIO -DWITH_OPENAL -DWITH_OPENEXR -DWITH_OPENGL -DWITH_OPENIMAGEIO -DWITH_OPENJPEG -DWITH_OPENSUBDIV -DWITH_OPENVDB -DWITH_POTRACE -DWITH_SDL -DWITH_SNDFILE -DWITH_TIFF -DWITH_XR_OPENXR -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__MMX__ -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE__ -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/python -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/blenkernel -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/blenlib -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/blenloader -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/blentranslation -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/depsgraph -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/editors/include -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/gpu -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/imbuf -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/makesdna -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/makesrna -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/windowmanager -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/clog -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/guardedalloc -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/mantaflow/extern -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/cycles/blender -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/freestyle/intern/python -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/openvdb -I....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/imbuf/intern/oiio -I....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opensubdiv -isystem /usr/include/python3.8 -isystem /usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2 -fmacro-prefix-map="....../blender-2.92.0/"="" -fmacro-prefix-map="....../blender-2.92.0/build/"="" -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT source/blender/python/intern/CMakeFiles/bf_python.dir/bpy_driver.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/bf_python.dir/bpy_driver.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/bf_python.dir/bpy_driver.c.o -c ....../blender-2.92.0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_driver.c
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc: In function ‘void updateGLSLShader(OCIO_GLSLShader*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::ConstProcessorRcPtr*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::ConstProcessorRcPtr*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::GpuShaderDesc*, const string&)’:
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:174:37: error: ‘using element_type = const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’ {aka ‘const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’} has no member named ‘getGpuShaderText’
  174 |     os << (*processor_scene_to_ui)->getGpuShaderText(*shader_desc) << "\n";
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:177:39: error: ‘using element_type = const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’ {aka ‘const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’} has no member named ‘getGpuShaderText’
  177 |     os << (*processpr_ui_to_display)->getGpuShaderText(*shader_desc) << "\n";
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc: In function ‘void updateGLSLLut3d(OCIO_GLSLLut3d*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::ConstProcessorRcPtr*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::ConstProcessorRcPtr*, OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::GpuShaderDesc*, const string&)’:
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:261:19: error: ‘using element_type = const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’ {aka ‘const class OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::Processor’} has no member named ‘getGpuLut3D’
  261 |     (*processor)->getGpuLut3D(lut_data, *shader_desc);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc: In member function ‘virtual bool OCIOImpl::setupGLSLDraw(OCIO_GLSLDrawState**, OCIO_ConstProcessorRcPtr__**, OCIO_ConstProcessorRcPtr__**, OCIO_CurveMappingSettings*, float, bool, bool)’:
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:500:17: error: ‘OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::GpuShaderDesc::GpuShaderDesc()’ is protected within this context
  500 |   GpuShaderDesc shaderDesc;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:41:
/usr/local/include/OpenColorIO/OpenColorIO.h:3140:5: note: declared protected here
 3140 |     GpuShaderDesc();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
....../blender-2.92.0/intern/opencolorio/ocio_impl_glsl.cc:500:17: error: cannot declare variable ‘shaderDesc’ to be of abstract type ‘OpenColorIO_v2_1dev::GpuShaderDesc’
  500 |   GpuShaderDesc shaderDesc;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
......
```

2. For **OpenImageIO**

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/blender
cd ....../blender-2.92.0/build/source/creator && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/blender.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/c++  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=c++17 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2 -fmacro-prefix-map="....../blender-2.92.0/"="" -fmacro-prefix-map="....../blender-2.92.0/build/"="" -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 -DNDEBUG  -no-pie   -Wl,--version-script='....../blender-2.92.0/source/creator/blender.map' CMakeFiles/blender.dir/creator.c.o CMakeFiles/blender.dir/creator_args.c.o CMakeFiles/blender.dir/creator_signals.c.o CMakeFiles/blender.dir/buildinfo.c.o -o ../../bin/blender   -L/usr/lib/llvm-11/lib  -L/tbb/lib  .....................................
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lextern_bullet
../../lib/libbf_imbuf_openimageio.a(openimageio_api.cpp.o):openimageio_api.cpp:function imb_load_photoshop: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::basesize() const'
../../lib/libbf_imbuf_openimageio.a(openimageio_api.cpp.o):openimageio_api.cpp:function imb_load_photoshop: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::clear_value()'
../../lib/libbf_imbuf_openimageio.a(openimageio_api.cpp.o):openimageio_api.cpp:function imb_load_photoshop: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::clear_value()'
../../lib/libbf_imbuf_openimageio.a(openimageio_api.cpp.o):openimageio_api.cpp:function OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ImageSpec::~ImageSpec(): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::clear_value()'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.cpp.o):blender_python.cpp:function ccl::osl_update_node_func(_object*, _object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::empty_std_string[abi:cxx11]'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.cpp.o):blender_python.cpp:function ccl::osl_update_node_func(_object*, _object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::empty_std_string[abi:cxx11]'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.cpp.o):blender_python.cpp:function ccl::osl_update_node_func(_object*, _object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::empty_std_string[abi:cxx11]'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.cpp.o):blender_session.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSession::do_write_update_render_result(BL::RenderLayer&, ccl::RenderTile&, bool): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::make_unique(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.cpp.o):blender_session.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSession::update_resumable_tile_manager(int): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::make_unique(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.cpp.o):blender_session.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSession::synchronize(BL::Depsgraph&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::make_unique(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.cpp.o):blender_session.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSession::stamp_view_layer_metadata(ccl::Scene*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::make_unique(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::clear_value()'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::init_noclear(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, int, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::Interp, void const*, bool)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat4'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::init_noclear(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, int, void const*, bool)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::init_noclear(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, int, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::Interp, void const*, bool)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function ccl::BlenderSync::sync_object_attributes(BL::DepsgraphObjectInstance&, ccl::Object*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::init_noclear(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, int, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::Interp, void const*, bool)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.cpp.o):blender_object.cpp:function void std::vector<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue, ccl::GuardedAllocator<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue> >::_M_realloc_insert<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue*, std::vector<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue, ccl::GuardedAllocator<OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue> > >, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::init_noclear(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, int, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ParamValue::Interp, void const*, bool)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.cpp.o):blender_shader.cpp:function ccl::add_node(ccl::Scene*, BL::RenderEngine&, BL::BlendData&, BL::Depsgraph&, BL::Scene&, ccl::ShaderGraph*, BL::ShaderNodeTree&, BL::ShaderNode&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::concat(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.cpp.o):blender_shader.cpp:function ccl::add_node(ccl::Scene*, BL::RenderEngine&, BL::BlendData&, BL::Depsgraph&, BL::Scene&, ccl::ShaderGraph*, BL::ShaderNodeTree&, BL::ShaderNode&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::concat(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_mesh.cpp.o):blender_mesh.cpp:function ccl::mikk_compute_tangents(BL::Mesh const&, char const*, ccl::Mesh*, bool, bool): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_mesh.cpp.o):blender_mesh.cpp:function ccl::mikk_compute_tangents(BL::Mesh const&, char const*, ccl::Mesh*, bool, bool): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeVector'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_volume.cpp.o):blender_volume.cpp:function ccl::sync_volume_object(BL::BlendData&, BL::Object&, ccl::Scene*, ccl::Volume*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat'
../../lib/libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_volume.cpp.o):blender_volume.cpp:function ccl::sync_volume_object(BL::BlendData&, BL::Object&, ccl::Scene*, ccl::Volume*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring::empty_std_string[abi:cxx11]'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::data_sizeof() const: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::data_sizeof() const: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeMatrix'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeColor'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypePoint'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeVector'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeNormal'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypePoint'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeVector'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::same_storage(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeNormal'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::add_with_weight(void*, void*, float): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::Attribute::add_with_weight(void*, void*, float): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeVector'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypePoint'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeNormal'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeNormal'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeMatrix'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypePoint'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(attribute.cpp.o):attribute.cpp:function ccl::AttributeSet::add(ccl::AttributeStandard, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeColor'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::extension[abi:cxx11](OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, bool)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::unique_path[abi:cxx11](OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::remove(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::rename(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::load_neighbors(ccl::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, ccl::GuardedAllocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, ccl::vector<int, ccl::GuardedAllocator<int> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::is_regular(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(denoising.cpp.o):denoising.cpp:function ccl::DenoiseImage::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::is_regular(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(geometry.cpp.o):geometry.cpp:function ccl::emit_attribute_map_entry(ccl::uint4*, int, unsigned int, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, ccl::AttributeDescriptor const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeMatrix'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(geometry.cpp.o):geometry.cpp:function ccl::update_attribute_element_size(ccl::Geometry*, ccl::Attribute*, ccl::AttributePrimitive, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*) [clone .part.0]: error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeMatrix'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(geometry.cpp.o):geometry.cpp:function ccl::GeometryManager::update_osl_attributes(ccl::Device*, ccl::Scene*, ccl::vector<ccl::AttributeRequestSet, ccl::GuardedAllocator<ccl::AttributeRequestSet> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeColor'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(geometry.cpp.o):geometry.cpp:function ccl::GeometryManager::update_osl_attributes(ccl::Device*, ccl::Scene*, ccl::vector<ccl::AttributeRequestSet, ccl::GuardedAllocator<ccl::AttributeRequestSet> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeColor'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(geometry.cpp.o):geometry.cpp:function ccl::GeometryManager::device_update_attributes(ccl::Device*, ccl::DeviceScene*, ccl::Scene*, ccl::Progress&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::basesize() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(image_oiio.cpp.o):image_oiio.cpp:function ccl::OIIOImageLoader::load_metadata(ccl::ImageMetaData&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::basesize() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(image_oiio.cpp.o):image_oiio.cpp:function ccl::OIIOImageLoader::load_metadata(ccl::ImageMetaData&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::is_floating_point() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(image_oiio.cpp.o):image_oiio.cpp:function ccl::OIIOImageLoader::load_metadata(ccl::ImageMetaData&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::basesize() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(image_oiio.cpp.o):image_oiio.cpp:function ccl::OIIOImageLoader::load_metadata(ccl::ImageMetaData&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::is_floating_point() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(merge.cpp.o):merge.cpp:function ccl::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ImageSpec const&, ccl::array<float, 16ul> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::extension[abi:cxx11](OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, bool)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(merge.cpp.o):merge.cpp:function ccl::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ImageSpec const&, ccl::array<float, 16ul> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::unique_path[abi:cxx11](OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(merge.cpp.o):merge.cpp:function ccl::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ImageSpec const&, ccl::array<float, 16ul> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::remove(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(merge.cpp.o):merge.cpp:function ccl::save_output(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ImageSpec const&, ccl::array<float, 16ul> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Filesystem::rename(OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeString'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeString'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeInt'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeInt'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeInt'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(ccl::ShaderNode*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeInt'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(char const*, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeString'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLCompiler::parameter(char const*, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeString'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLShaderManager::shading_system_init(): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view::c_str() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLShaderManager::shading_system_init(): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::string_view::c_str() const'
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLShaderManager::OSLShaderManager(): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ErrorHandler'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
../../lib/libcycles_render.a(osl.cpp.o):osl.cpp:function ccl::OSLShaderManager::osl_compile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ErrorHandler::default_handler()'
../../lib/libcycles_kernel_osl.a(osl_services.cpp.o):osl_services.cpp:function ccl::get_primitive_attribute(ccl::KernelGlobals*, ccl::ShaderData const*, ccl::OSLGlobals::Attribute const&, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc const&, bool, void*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat4'
../../lib/libcycles_kernel_osl.a(osl_services.cpp.o):osl_services.cpp:function ccl::OSLRenderServices::get_attribute(ccl::ShaderData*, bool, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc, OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::ustring, void*): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::TypeDesc::TypeFloat4'
../../lib/libcycles_util.a(util_path.cpp.o):util_path.cpp:function ccl::path_get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Sysutil::this_program_path[abi:cxx11]()'
../../lib/libcycles_util.a(util_path.cpp.o):util_path.cpp:function ccl::path_user_get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Sysutil::this_program_path[abi:cxx11]()'
../../lib/libcycles_util.a(util_system.cpp.o):util_system.cpp:function ccl::system_call_self(ccl::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, ccl::GuardedAllocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&): error: undefined reference to 'OpenImageIO_v2_4_0::Sysutil::this_program_path[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/build.make:397: bin/blender] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '....../blender-2.92.0/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6318: source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '....../blender-2.92.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:169: all] Error 2
```

Can anybody help please?

Cheers
Pei

Comment: In as much as you can change the source by changing git branch, will also need to reconfigure cmake files, cmake-gui is a handy tool. Delete a branch and reconfigure, manually point to a particular version lib (often using  /opt/libs) if need be  (if building with cmake)  IIRC was building late 2.79s against python 3.9. with no issue  When I decided to stop building (crash hassles, issues like above) was a little surprised to see downloaded version of blender used python 3.7.. Questions re building blender were once closed pretty quickly as off-topic.  There have been some meta posts about

Comment: this changing. Not sure where it's at.  Tried to find a great link re missing libs, anyhow heres another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library